# Join and multiply RDDs in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, mapping, rdd

I have two RDDs which I want to multiply by key. That can be done either by merging the two RDDs and multiplying the elements or by multiplying the RDDs without merging them.

Say I have these two RDDs:

```
rdd1 = [("dog", 2), ("ox", 4), ("cat", 1)]
rdd2 = [("dog", 9), ("ox", 2), ("cat", 2)]
```

What I want is:

```
multiplied_rdd = [("dog", 18), ("ox", 8), ("cat", 2)]
```

I tried merging the two RDDs, and then I would multiply the numbers, but I am getting an error:

```
merged_rdd = rdd1.join(rdd2)
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
```

If I manage to get the merged RDD I would do:

```
multiplied = merged_rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1][0]*x[1][1])
```

So, my question is how can I achieve the "multiplied_rdd" RDD either by joining or by multiplying externally rdd1 and rdd2?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are initializing RDDs (you have two `rdd1`), but this should work:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

rdd1 = [("dog", 2), ("ox", 4), ("cat", 1)]
rdd2 = [("dog", 9), ("ox", 2), ("cat", 2)]

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
x = sc.parallelize(rdd1)
y = sc.parallelize(rdd2)
merged_rdd = x.join(y)
multiplied = merged_rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1][0] * x[1][1]))

print(multiplied.collect())
# [('ox', 8), ('dog', 18), ('cat', 2)]
```